# ConvLSTM2d running slower on colab GPU than CPU

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, google-colaboratory

I am training a convLSTM2d model which is running extremely slow on colabs GPU with a batch size of 8.

Currently, the ETA for each epoch is 3 hours. I have checked and I have GPU enabled. I also ran a comparison using only a CPU and the ETA per epoch reduced to 1.5 hours. What could be the reason for this? Is convLSTM2d not available on Cuda? Here is my model below, thanks for any pointers.

```
conv_2d = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.ConvLSTM2D(32, kernel_size=(5,1), padding='same',
                             return_sequences=False, input_shape=[30, 14, 1, 1]),
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
  tf.keras.layers.RepeatVector(look_forward),
  tf.keras.layers.Reshape((look_forward, 14, 1, 32)),
  tf.keras.layers.ConvLSTM2D(32, kernel_size=(5,1), padding='same',
                             return_sequences=True),
  tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='relu'))
])

conv_2d.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError(),
                  optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(clipnorm=1.0),
                  metrics=[tf.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError()])

history = conv_2d.fit(train, epochs=MAX_EPOCHS,
                        validation_data=val,
                        steps_per_epoch= STEPS_PER_EPOCH,
                        validation_steps=VALIDATION_STEPS)
```

Comment: I just looked at the source code and it seems that ConvLSTM2d doesn't have a cuda implementation.

Comment: That could be a dealbreaker - not being able to speed training using GPUs (unless it's really fast on CPU).